# Remove focus from select2 durandel/ko widget

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, durandal

Focus on the select2 dropdown/select box causes issues on mobile. The keyboard appears and overlaps the options - a common and well known issue. One that I have a solution for... https://jsfiddle.net/yw61h28z/

My app uses Durandel and knockout and trying to apply this fix seems impossible. My jquery is being ignored, I think it has something to do with durandal composition but not entirely sure.

**View -**

```
<div data-bind="attr: {'id': field.id + 'container'}">
    <span class="linkify" data-bind="text: field.title"></span>
    <span class="requiredAsterisk" data-bind="visible: field.mandatory">*</span>
    <div data-bind="attr: {'id': field.id}">

        <select id="dataCombo" class="form-control"
                data-bind="autocomplete: {items: field.options,
                                          idField: 'key', textField: 'value',
                                          onSelect: handleSelection,
                                          multiple: true}"
                style="width: 100%"></select>

    </div>
</div>
```

**viewmodel.js -**

```
define(['jquery','knockout'], function ($,ko) {
    function PickListMultiViewModel () {
        var self = this;

        self.activate = function(input) {
            self.field = input.data;
        };

        self.handleSelection = function (selectedOptions) {
            if(!selectedOptions) {
                return self.field.value();
            }
            self.field.value(_.map(selectedOptions, 'key'));
        };

       <!-- remove focus -->
        $("#dataCombo").select2({
            closeOnSelect: false
        });
        $("#dataCombo").on('select2:open', function (e, i) {
            $(document.activeElement).blur()
        });
       <!-- remove focus end -->
    }

    return PickListMultiViewModel;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without an example that reproduces the problem, but there's a general rule you should follow:

*Accessing the DOM should not be done in view models, but **only** in binding handlers*.

At the time of your view model creation, knockout could easily have removed the targeted element from the DOM. One `if` binding and your widget breaks. Binding handlers' `init` methods are executed any time an element is data-bound.

Here's what a binding handler for your `select2` could look like (but I'd advice you to google if somebody else ever created one):

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.select2 = {
  init: function(element) {
    var $el = $(element);
    var dispose = function() {
      $el.select2("data", null);
    };

    $el.select2({
      closeOnSelect: false
    });

    $el.on('select2:open', function(e, i) {
      $(document.activeElement).blur()
    });

    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal
      .addDisposeCallback(element, dispose);
  }
}
```